# Adding a columns to a pandas dataframe inside a function without warning

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function like:

```
def add_col(df):
  df['foo'] = df['bar'].map({'x': True, 'y': False}
  return df
```

Now if I call it, I get:

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.

I tried changing it to:

```
def add_col(df):
  df.loc[:, 'foo'] = df['bar'].map({'x': True, 'y': False}
  return df
```

But that didn't remove the warning. Is there a proper way to do this without suppressing / ignoring the warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you create the column , you input df is subset of another

```
 df = sumdf[cond].copy()
```

Or use `assign` fix it

```
def add_col(df):
    return   df.assign(foo=df['bar'].map({'x': True, 'y': False}))

add_col(df)
```